# Task failed with an exception. - React-Native / Gradle / Android / iOS app

Tags: react-native, gradle

Can someone help me get this working?
https://github.com/rachhen/DogWalk

Just by running it from CMD
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO7IJ.png)

And trying to build it in Android Studio
I added the implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.9' in dependencies
and changed apply plugin: 'maven' to maven-publish
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YsyV.png)

Also tried commenting this out:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbwen.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.